# 'NgxTypeaheadModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.(-996002)

Tags: angular

I install 'NgxTypeahead', when I compiler angular project. I get this error:

```
'NgxTypeaheadModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.(-996002)
ngx-typeahead.module.d.ts(1, 22): This likely means that the library (ngx-typeahead) 
which declares NgxTypeaheadModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer 
version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the 
library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
(alias) class NgxTypeaheadModule
```

my version of angular:

```
"@angular/cli": "~16.2.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.0",
```

how fix this promlam?

thank.

Comment: Have you imported `NgxTypeaheadModule` in your imports array of your module?

Answer (score 0):

I returned a version of angular/cli from 16.2.0 to 14.2.12

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).